# What if the GM is the one who is traditional?

Tags: dungeon-world

In creating my character, I'm asking a lot of questions. I'm also studying the rules for my own benefit of what is expected of me. (We are all new to DW.)

I am reading a lot of stuff (much of it here on SE) about how the GM has rules they have to follow, and how many decisions are expected to be decided by the table, rather than GM fiat.

I am (perhaps prematurely) anticipating some conflict with the GM if I offer things I understand about the game but go against what might be considered traditional 'GM is God' philosophy.

As examples - if I understand them correctly:

1. all players are supposed to watch for things that trigger a move by other players.
2. or a GM cannot simply make a move - say, springing a trap on a thief - without the required move occurring to trigger it.

I anticipate simply being overridden by the GM, not because his rationale makes sense but because - essentially - GMs traditionally had no constraints on their actions.

How do I resolve my understanding of game-play with the GM's idea of game-play, while avoiding the confrontational act of, say, quoting the rules to him? (This will not go well.)

Or do I play as if following the most basic player's guide: the character sheet and moves? (i.e. I don't need to know the *game* rules in order to play my character.)

Comment: So, just to check, you're expecting your GM to be [this guy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48251/15469) and you're looking for advice on how to deal with that?

Comment: ERm. Sortta. More like his intentions are good but not so much with the 'talking to him about it' thing. Challenging play has generally resulted in a defensive reaction - to the point where, by my perception, it will be taken as a  "just another" example of me "being difficult".

Comment: And man, If he reads SE, I am sunk...

Comment: Actually. My question is inappropriate for SE.

This is a social dynamics problem, not a DW problem.

I will (try to) delete it in the morning. There is already a thread that answers this question.

Comment: Fair, I'll delete my answer and VTC this as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @DaveC426913 We do actually handle social dynamics questions that impact playing RPGs. It’s an important part of our topic, being an inherently social activity, so these sorts of things are solidly on-topic. We you start playing in this game, if run into specific social frictions, please feel welcome to ask more. :)